# How to show required request body using django rest framework + drf_spectacular + swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I started using drf_spectacular and swagger recently, I have a an API endpoint that expects request body with field in it, however I can't seem to understand how to reveal this in the UI.

my view:

```
    @extend_schema(
    responses={200: TripSerializer},
)
def get(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    trip = TripService.get_trip(trip_id=request.data.get("trip_id"))
    if trip is None:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    trip_serializer = TripSerializer(trip)
    return Response(trip_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

my request body:

```
{
"trip_id": "1"
}
```

my swagger UI ps

[image]

will appriciate any help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to the schema:

```
@extend_schema(
        request=InputSerializer,
        responses={200: TripSerializer}
    )
```

If you don't have already the InputSerializer, just create it:

```
class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
   trip_id = seriarlizer.IntegerField()
```